# What does running the multiarch/qemu-user-static does before building a container?

Tags: docker, qemu

Can someone explain me in simple terms what does

```
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes -c yes
```

do when called right before doing a `docker build` a container from a Dockerfile?

I have the notion that it is to permit the use of containers from other architectures into the X86 architecture, but I am not sure I quite understand the explanation I found in some sites.

Does the presence of the above instruction(`docker run`) implies that the Dockerfile of the build stage is for another architecture?

Answer (score 16):

I too had this question recently, and I don't have a complete answer, but here is what I do know, or at least believe:

### Setup & Test

The magic to setup - required once per reboot of system, is just this:

```bash
# start root's docker (not via any `-rootless` scripts, obviously)
sudo systemctl start docker
# setup QEMU static executables formats
sudo docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
# test
docker run --rm -t arm64v8/ubuntu uname -m
# shoudl expect:
# >> aarch64
# optional: shutdown root's docker
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

Note that the test example assumes that you are running that your own personal "rootless-"`docker`, therefore as yourself, not as `root` (nor via `sudo`), and it works just dandy.

### Gory Details

... which are important if you want to **understand** how/why this works.

The main sources for this info:

- https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/
- https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static (what we are using)
- https://hub.docker.com/r/multiarch/qemu-user-static/ (using `buildx` to build multi/cross-arch images)
- https://dbhi.github.io/qus/related.html (an alternative to `qemu-user-static`)
- https://github.com/dbhi/qus (source repo for above)
- https://dev.to/asacasa/how-to-set-up-binfmtmisc-for-qemu-the-hard-way-3bl4 (manual curation of same)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc

The fundamental trick to making this work is to install new "magic" strings into the kernel process space so that when an (ARM) executable is run inside a docker image, it recognizes the bin-fmt and uses the QEMU interpreter (from the `multiarch/*` docker image) to execute it.  Before we setup the bin formats, the contents look like this:

```
root@odysseus # mount | grep binfmt_misc
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=35,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=45170)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
root@odysseus # ls /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/
jar  llvm-6.0-runtime.binfmt  python2.7  python3.6  python3.7  python3.8  register  sbcl  status
```

After we start (root's) `dockerd` and setup the formats:

```
root@odysseus # systemctl start docker
root@odysseus # docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
Setting /usr/bin/qemu-alpha-static as binfmt interpreter for alpha
Setting /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static as binfmt interpreter for arm
[...]
root@odysseus # ls /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/
jar                      python3.8        qemu-armeb       qemu-microblazeel  qemu-mipsn32    qemu-ppc64le  qemu-sh4eb        qemu-xtensaeb
llvm-6.0-runtime.binfmt  qemu-aarch64     qemu-hexagon     qemu-mips          qemu-mipsn32el  qemu-riscv32  qemu-sparc        register
python2.7                qemu-aarch64_be  qemu-hppa        qemu-mips64        qemu-or1k       qemu-riscv64  qemu-sparc32plus  sbcl
python3.6                qemu-alpha       qemu-m68k        qemu-mips64el      qemu-ppc        qemu-s390x    qemu-sparc64      status
python3.7                qemu-arm         qemu-microblaze  qemu-mipsel        qemu-ppc64      qemu-sh4      qemu-xtensa
```

Now we can run an ARM version of ubuntu:

```
root@odysseus # docker run --rm -t arm64v8/ubuntu uname -m
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64/v8) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
aarch64
```

The warning is to be expected since the host CPU is AMD, and can be gotten rid of by specifying the platform to docker:

```
root@odysseus # docker run --rm --platform linux/arm64 -t arm64v8/ubuntu uname -m
aarch64
```

### How does this really work?

At the base of it is just QEMU's ability to interpose a DBM (dynamic binary modification) interpreter to translate the instruction set of one system to that of the underlying platform.

The only trick we have to do is tell the underlying system where to find those interpreters.  Thats what the `qemu-user-static` image does in registering the binary format magic strings / interpreters.  So, what's in those `binfmt`s?

```
root@odysseus # cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-aarch64
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static
flags: F
offset 0
magic 7f454c460201010000000000000000000200b700
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff
```

Huh - that's interesting, especially because on the host system there is **no** `/usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static`, and it's not in the target image either, so where does this thing live?  It's in the `qemu-user-static` image itself, with the appropriate tag of the form: `<HOST-ARCH>-<GUEST-ARCH>`, as in `multiarch/qemu-user-static:x86_64-aarch64`.

```bash
# Not on the local system
odysseus % ls /usr/bin/qemu*
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/qemu*': No such file or directory

# Not in the target image
odysseus % docker run --rm --platform linux/arm64 -t arm64v8/ubuntu bash -c 'ls /usr/bin/qemu*'
/usr/bin/ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/qemu*': No such file or directory

# where is it?
odysseus % docker run --rm multiarch/qemu-user-static:x86_64-aarch64 sh -c 'ls /usr/bin/qemu*'
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
# Hmm, no `sh` in that image - let's try directly...
odysseus % docker run --rm multiarch/qemu-user-static:x86_64-aarch64 /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static --version
qemu-aarch64 version 7.0.0 (Debian 1:7.0+dfsg-7)
Copyright (c) 2003-2022 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

# AHA - there it is.
```

That's the real magic that I don't yet quite understand.  Somehow `docker` is, I believe, using that image to spin up the QEMU interpreter, and then feeding it the code from the actual image/container you want to run, as in the `uname` example from earlier.    Some web-searching left me unsatiated as to how this magic is achieved, but I'm guessing if I kept following links from here I might find the true source of that slight-of-hand.

- https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/

Comment: Hi.. Amazing work!  Edit to add "apparently enter submits"!      So.. Did you ever find out how the interpreter persists? It's like black magic. And now there are 2. the multiarch/qemu-user-static and the tonistiigi/binfmt.    but the docker container the registered the emulator is long gone when the next thing needs to run it.  Did you ever find out how that persists?

Comment: Hi, thanks for very good explanation. I am trying to build Linux wheel for aarch64 using this QEMU emulator. But when I do `docker run --rm -v `pwd`:/io quay.io/pypa/manylinux2014_aarch64 bash -c '/opt/python/cp38-cp38/bin/python ./setup.py bdist_wheel'` I get the error `/opt/python/cp38-cp38/bin/python: can't open file './setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @Preeti - that deserves it's own question, and you'll probably get better traction that way.

Answer (score 4):

To complement @crimson-egret's answer: The **`fix-binary`** flag in `binfmt_misc` was used to make the statically compiled qemu emulator work across different namespaces/chroots/containers.

In the [doc](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html) for `binfmt_misc` you can find the explanation of the `fix-binary` flag:

> F - fix binary
>
> The usual behaviour of binfmt_misc is to spawn the binary lazily when the misc format file is invoked. However, this doesn’t work very well in the face of mount namespaces and changeroots, so the F mode **opens the binary as soon as the emulation is installed and uses the opened image to spawn the emulator, meaning it is always available once installed, regardless of how the environment changes**.

This [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu/+bug/1815100) also explained:

> ...
> The fix-binary flag of binfmt is meant to specifically deal with this. The interpreter file (e.g. qemu-arm-static) is loaded when its binfmt rule is installed instead of when a file that requires it is encountered. When the kernel then encounters a file which requires that interpreter it simply execs the already open file descriptor instead of opening a new one (IOW: **the kernel already has the correct file descriptor open, so possibly divergent roots no longer play into finding the interpreter thus allowing namespaces/containers/chroots of a foreign architecture to be run like native ones**).

If you use the qemu-user-static image without the `-p yes` option, the `fix-binary` flag won't be added, and running the arm64 container won't work because now the kernel will actually try to open the qemu emulator in the container's root filesystem:

```bash
$ docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset
[...]

$ cat /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-aarch64
enabled
interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-aarch64-static
flags:
offset 0
magic 7f454c460201010000000000000000000200b700
mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff

$ docker run --rm -t arm64v8/ubuntu uname -m
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/arm64/v8) does not match the detected host platform (linux/amd64) and no specific platform was requested
exec /usr/bin/uname: no such file or directory
failed to resize tty, using default size
```